# ODE IVP: $y'-2y=e^t$, $y(0)=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, initial-value-problems

> **Question**:
> $$y'-2y=e^t\quad ;\quad y(0)=0$$

When I tried to solve with integrating factor, I got $y=-e^t$, which can never satisfy the initial value condition.

Comment: You certainly forgot the constant of intgeration

Answer (score 3):

$$y'-2y=e^t$$
$$(ye^{-2t})'=e^{-t}$$
Don't forget the constant of integration:
$$ye^{-2t}=-e^{-t} +c$$
$$y(t)=-e^t+ce^{2t}$$
Apply initial condition:
$$y(0)=0 \implies c=1$$
$$y(t)=e^{2t}-e^t$$